# Gathering statistics on agent population

Tags: anylogic

I have some issues with gathering statistics on the population level in a model I've been working with.
In the model I have an agent type Company and RawMaterial. Within Company a process flow exists, where on some blocks costs are assigned to a variable in Company upon entry of RawMaterial (e.g. `cost = gamma(3, 125, 0);`)

To calculate the Company-level cumulative costs I use a Statistics object with `cost` in the value field of this object.
So far so good it seems.

However, when I want to sum the cumulative costs of all Company agents into one value I run into trouble. Ideally, I want the cumulative costs for each Company agent to be plotted in Main.
I've looked at the Help file (section "Functions to collect statistics on agent population") with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about doing this in main? (you can even put this function in your time plot)

```
sum( companies, c->c.cost );
```

This function calculates the sum of the costs of all company agents (as long as you have a population of agents called companies in main, and not only an agent type)

If you don't have companies as a population of agents, you have to create it, otherwise it's very difficult to calculate anything. How to create it depends on your model.

Comment: Thank you, Felipe. I know it is difficult without actually seeing the model, but unfortunately, this returns costs a `time = t`, aggregated over all companies. What I want is that costs over all `t` are summed, and aggregated over all Company agents. And yes, the Company agents live in main.

Comment: then instead of cost = gamma(3, 125, 0); you should do cost = cost+gamma(3, 125, 0);